# Como comparar com if com todos os item do array em php?

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho um array com varios itens e quero que o if veja se algum deles é a palavra certa sem informar o numero do array

```php
<?php 

$variascoisas = array("Kadu", "Eloah");

if ($variascoisas == "Eloah") {
    echo "a";
}

?>
```

Comment: Já tentou usar um comando de repetição? Tipo um `for`, `while` ou `repeat`? Assim pode percorrer o array inteiro e fazer a comparação com cada item do array.

Comment: Você pode utilizar `in_array($palavra, $variascoisas)` para checar se um determinado valor existe dentro do seu array, para mais detalhes olhe [isso](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score -1):

```php
<?php

$variascoisas = array("Kadu", "Eloah");

if (in_array("Eloah", $variascoisas)) {
    echo "Presente!";
} else {
    echo "Eloah não veio";
}

?>
```

Fonte: [Função in_array php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).